# How to fix uncaught TypeError Failed to construct 'Headers': Invalid name at getNews , I'm using newsapi

Tags: javascript, html, api, newsapi

I'm trying to make a basic project using newsapi.org, but I'm getting an err of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Headers': Invalid name
    at getNews (index.js:4:16)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

& Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received.

`

```
function getNews() {
  fetch(
    "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=<My ApiKey>",
    { headers: new Headers({ "X-Requested With": "abcd" }) }
  )
    .then((a) => a.json())
    .then((response) => {
      for (let i = 0; response < response.articles.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +=
          "<div class='article'> <img class='image' src='+response.articles[i].urlToImage+' > </div> <h1>" +
          response.articles[i].title +
          "</h1>" +
          response.articles[i].source.name +
          "<br>" +
          response.articles[i].description +
          "<a href=" +
          response.articles[i].url +
          "target='_blank'>" +
          response.articles[i].url +
          "</a></div>";
      }
    });
}
```

`I think problem is with innerHTML.`

```
<body>
    <button class="btn" onclick="getNews()">Get News Here.</button>
    <div class="output"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
```

`

I was hoping to see the news articles load dynamically but instead had this error!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Failed to construct 'Headers': Invalid name
```

The reason for this error is because `With` is separated by a space in the `X-Requested With` header.

```
 new Headers({ "X-Requested With": "..." }) }
```

You must write with a hyphen(`-`).
Replace with `X-Requested-With`

Comment: Hey, thanks, - worked... but had more errors after that and fixed them so right now I don't have any errors but still, when I click on the get news button it doesn't display the dynamic div, the console is blank as well!! more help pls!!

Comment: First of all, sorry for the late reply, I've been very busy these days. Maybe you solved the problem but `document.getElementById("output")` in this line you are trying to get the element with `getElementById` but `output` is a class. You should do `document.querySelector(".output")`.

Comment: Thank you so much kanvil, I figured it out.